# lexer that takes "not" but not "not like"

Tags: java, parsing, antlr, grammar, lexer

I need a small trick to get my parser completely working.
I use antlr to parse boolean queries.

a query is composed of elements, linked together by ands, ors and nots.

So I can have something like :

```
"(P or not Q or R) or (( not A  and B) or C)"
```

Thing is, an element can be long, and is generally in the form :

```
a an_operator b
```

for example :

```
"New-York matches NY"
```

Trick, one of the an_operator is "not like"

So I would like to modify my lexer so that the not checks that there is no like after it, to avoid parsing elements containing "not like" operators.

My current grammar is here :

```
// save it in a file called Logic.g
grammar Logic;

options {
  output=AST;
}

// parser/production rules start with a lower case letter
parse
  :  expression EOF!    // omit the EOF token
  ;

expression
  :  orexp
  ;

orexp
  :  andexp ('or'^ andexp)*    // make `or` the root
  ;

andexp
  :  notexp ('and'^ notexp)*      // make `and` the root
  ;

notexp
  :  'not'^ atom    // make `not` the root
  |  atom
  ;

atom
  :  ID
  |  '('! expression ')'!    // omit both `(` andexp `)`
  ;

// lexer/terminal rules start with an upper case letter
ID    : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z')+;
Space : (' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n')+ {$channel=HIDDEN;};
```

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks !

Comment: I speak lex and yacc, not not Antlr.  The typical solution in lex is to recognize keywords and operators explicitly; the parser spec doesn't.  In Antlr, can you not write a production like "'not like'^ atom"?

Comment: @DavidGorsline, I wouldn't make `not like` an unary operator like `not` is. The `not` typically negates a boolean expression, while `not like` compares 2 values (a left- and right-hand side of the expression). Also, creating a token that matches `'not like'` will cause problems when there are more spaces in between, or when the lexer stumbles upon input like `'not likes'` or `'not lik'` (this will cause the lexer to trip, just as gnu-lex will, I believe, but I don't speak *that* too fluently though :))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a possible solution:

```
grammar Logic;

options {
  output=AST;
}

tokens {
  NOT_LIKE;
}

parse
  :  expression EOF!
  ;

expression
  :  orexp
  ;

orexp
  :  andexp (Or^ andexp)*
  ;

andexp
  :  fuzzyexp (And^ fuzzyexp)*
  ;

fuzzyexp
  :  (notexp -> notexp) ( Matches e=notexp  -> ^(Matches $fuzzyexp $e)
                        | Not Like e=notexp -> ^(NOT_LIKE $fuzzyexp $e)
                        | Like e=notexp     -> ^(Like $fuzzyexp $e)
                        )?
  ;

notexp
  :  Not^ atom
  |  atom
  ;

atom
  :  ID
  |  '('! expression ')'!
  ;

And     : 'and';
Or      : 'or';
Not     : 'not';
Like    : 'like';
Matches : 'matches';
ID      : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z')+;
Space   : (' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n')+ {$channel=HIDDEN;};
```

which will parse the input `"A not like B or C like D and (E or not F) and G matches H"` into the following AST:

[image]

Comment: thank you very much, it is good to see some more g code :). I really search for a way for "not like" to be completely discarded though, as I use another parsing technique for those. I would search for a "A NOT LIKE B primary", and "C like D". Only OR, NOT, AND and parenthesis should be processed in fact

Comment: @jlengrand, I'm no sure what you mean by "completely discarded". Do you want to skip these tokens? A bit more detail would help. Please don't use the comment boxes for your explanation: edit your original question instead.

Comment: @jlengrand, no, it's still not clear to me. You say you *'"not like" should not be processed'*, but what does that mean? Skipped from the stream? Tokenized as something else (what then?)? I posted an example of how the parser generated from my example grammar constructs an AST for the input `"A not like B or C like D and (E or not F) and G matches H"`. Now, can you indicate what AST you're trying to create instead? Not in words, but as a real image like I posted (can be an ASCII image, of course).

Comment: Hi. Sorry for the delay. I have been reconsidering my method and I think it is more useful to spend some time really learning the way Antlr works rather than just running for a quick fix. I'll try to use only one parser instead of two, so your answer is perfect for this question. Thank you very much